# ReactJS unit test says TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, ts-jest

My project works fine, but when I type the command `yarn test` to run the test, then it shows this error:

[image]

I think this error happened because of REDUX_DEVTOOLS in store, here is my store setup with REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION:

```
const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, UserReducer);

const reducers = combineReducers({
    persistedStore: persistedReducer,
    aoiStore: AoiReducer,
    aoi: AoiEventReducer,
    opticalDataStore: OpticalDataReducer,
    loaderStore: LoaderReducer,
});

export const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk),
        (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
            (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
    ),
);

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

For your info, if I remove this line from the store then it works fine:

```
(window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
    (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
```

Can anyone tell me where I made the mistake?

Comment: You should check full file. Maybe this error is not in line 34 :)

Comment: Could you provide us source code of params in `createStore`?

Comment: @JózefPodlecki Updated code, you can check it.

Answer (score 1):

You should never import the actual `store` file in your test. [redux-mock-store](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store) is a wonderful package which gives you the capability to mock the store according to you test file requirement.